# asynchronous manipulation of data in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, angular-promise

i am really new in this, and i have troubles manipulating data in the frontEnd of a app that i´m developing.

I have two functions called "getTipoEtapas()" and "getEtapasporTransfo" that uses two services to bring back data of the backend and assign them to a variables.

I have a third functions that initiate clicking a button in a HTML file. This one calls a fourth function that makes some other stuff.

The problem is that in the fourth function, i'm getting emptys values (data5, data6, data7). I thought that was a asynchronous problem, so i decided to start to use promises. 
But i repeat it, i am really new developer, so i tried to solve it, and didn´t work.

Sorry for my bad English.

this is the code:

```js
getTipoEtapas(){
  this.tipoEtapaService.getTipoEtapas().subscribe(tipoEtapa=>{
    this.data6=tipoEtapa;      
  })
}

getEtapasporTransfo(id:number){
  this.etapaService.getEtapasPorIdTransfo(id).subscribe(etapa=>{
    this.data5=etapa;
  })
}

onRowClicked(row){
  this.data2=row;
  const promesa=new Promise((resolve,rejected)=>{
    this.getEtapasporTransfo(this.data2.idTransfo)
    this.getTipoEtapas();  
    resolve('Resolved');
  });
  promesa.then(()=>{
  this.asignarEtapaTransfo();
  })
}

asignarEtapaTransfo(){
  console.log(this.data5);
  console.log(this.data6);
  console.log(this.data7);

  this.data5.forEach((e,i)=>{
    this.data6.forEach((e,j)=>{
      if(this.data5[i].idTipoEtapa==this.data6[j].idTipoEtapa)
      {
          this.data7[i].nombreEtapa=this.data6[j].nombreEtapa;
      }
    });

    this.data7[i].dateIni=this.data5[i].dateIni;
    this.data7[i].dateFin=this.data5[i].dateFin;
    this.data7[i].tiempoParc=this.data5[i].tiempoParc;
    this.data7[i].tiempoFin=this.data5[i].tiempoFin;   
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use async await to achieve. I simply provide an example for understanding and you can modify based upon your requirement. You can make `asyn`c function which returns a promise and you have to use `awai`t in the called function.

```
public async callFn1(): Promise<any> {
        let results: any[] = [];
        const somePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    //Perform some operations and get the results
                    resolve(results);
                });

        })
        console.log(results);
        return somePromise;
    }

    public async callFn2(): Promise<void> {
        let results: any[] = await test.callFn1(); // Here test is the object
        console.log(typeof results);
        results.forEach((obj)=>console.log(obj['Some Key']));

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that inside your promise you aren't waiting for the 2 observables to complete. You are setting them both up and then immediately returning a resolved promise.

I would recommend using RxJS all the way through here, rather than combining observables and promises.

Use `forkJoin` to run multiple observables together and return a combined result when they complete.

```js
data2;
data5;
data6;
data7;

getTipoEtapas(): Observable<any> {
  return this.tipoEtapaService.getTipoEtapas().pipe(
    tap(tipoEtapa => this.data6 = tipoEtapa)
  )
}

getEtapasporTransfo(id:number): Observable<any> {
  return this.etapaService.getEtapasPorIdTransfo(id).pipe(
    tap(etapa => this.data5 = etapa)
  );
}

onRowClicked(row) {
  this.data2 = row;
  forkJoin([
    this.getEtapasporTransfo(this.data2.idTransfo),
    this.getTipoEtapas()
  ]).subscribe(() => {
    this.asignarEtapaTransfo()
  });    
}

asignarEtapaTransfo(){
  console.log(this.data5);
  console.log(this.data6);
  console.log(this.data7);

  this.data5.forEach((e,i)=>{
    this.data6.forEach((e,j)=>{
      if(this.data5[i].idTipoEtapa==this.data6[j].idTipoEtapa)
      {
          this.data7[i].nombreEtapa=this.data6[j].nombreEtapa;
      }
    });

    this.data7[i].dateIni=this.data5[i].dateIni;
    this.data7[i].dateFin=this.data5[i].dateFin;
    this.data7[i].tiempoParc=this.data5[i].tiempoParc;
    this.data7[i].tiempoFin=this.data5[i].tiempoFin;   
  });
}
```

#### Keeping state within the observable chain

My example above is almost exactly the same as yours, except I am using `forkJoin` to wait for the observables to complete.

`onRowClicked` can be simplified by passing the result of the `forkJoin` into `asignarEtapaTransfo`.

```js
onRowClicked(row) {
  forkJoin({
    data5: this.etapaService.getEtapasPorIdTransfo(row.idTransfo),
    data6: this.tipoEtapaService.getTipoEtapas()
  }).subscribe(result => {
    this.asignarEtapaTransfo(result.data5, result.data6);
  });    
}

asignarEtapaTransfo(data5, data6) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! i tried your solution, it worked, But i got this new error in the browser console: 
Cannot set property 'dateIni' of undefined.
i defined up before the constructor of the class this data7 in this way: 

`code this.data7:EtapaTransfo[]=[];`

Comment: That's because `data7[i]` is undefined. You need to have some kind of object there if you want to set property values on it.